# How to make 3d rotation of uiview like ios 7 uipickerview type

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uiview, rotation

How to make 3d rotation of uiview like ios 7 uipickerview structure. It will look like 3d wheel of some width

Thanks in advance.

Comment: sorrry i can not get you,.

Answer (score 3):

I think this is one that can help you (if it still needed or for those who come here later)

```
CATransform3DMakeRotation
```

Example:

```
lable.layer.transfortm = CATransform3DMakeRotation(angle * M_PI/360, 1, 0, 0);
```

This will rotate `label` on x axis by specified `angle`, so you can change this value depending on label position in scroll view of your custom picker.

Also just read docs about `CATransform3D`